# How to solve FATAL EXCEPTION with Java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is My Code Snippet which perform a Search operation based on the text entered in a EditText Box, Please have a look on it...

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
        b4.setVisibility(b4.VISIBLE);   
        textlength=ed.getText().length();
        arr_sort.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length())
            {
            boolean b=ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0, textlength));
            if(b)
                {
                    arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                    //Log.i("In If:",arr_sort.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(BasicsActivity.this,R.layout.rowlayout2 ,R.id.label, arr_sort));
        //Log.i("Step6-","ok");
        }
        });
```

Now the Problem is when I write anything on the EditText View while Running it shows a RunTime FATALException with some NullPointerException..Please suggest me some some way out of here..
The Excpetions are as follows..

```
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at com.android.desitranslation.BasicsActivity$1.onTextChanged(BasicsActivity.java:65)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6295)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6336)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6485)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:195)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:132)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:4433)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:4267)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1256)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3855)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2560)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2535)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-02 13:29:48.577: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(541):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It would help if you told us which line was line 65 (that's the line that generated the null pointer exception). You're using a lot of external variables in onTextChanged(); probably one of them, or one of the array slots, is `null`.

Comment: I second Ted Hopp's request for telling us which one is line 65, and I dare to guess thats going to be the one with  ed.getText().toString()

Comment: The Line no 65 is the if condition i.e.;  if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length()){...}

Comment: what is lv_arr? How do you fill it?

Comment: What Vladimir is getting at is that either lv_arr or lv_arr[i] is null at that point. Use the debugger to find out which, or just examine your code to see why one of these isn't being given a value. Maybe you need to test (`if (lv_arr != null && lv_arr[i] != null && ...)`).

Comment: I got it... Actually the value of the lv_arr[i] which is a List is returning a null value because of which it shows the NullPointerException...Let me clarify it..Thanks to all for your suggestions..

Comment: Post this as an answer, please, and don't forget to mark it as accepted when it will be available.

Comment: you yourself has to accept the answer by clicking the arrow placed nearer to your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here in the Line No 65, which is nothing but a If(condition) i.e.;

```
if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length())
{..}
```

gets the `Null Pointer Exception` Because the value of the List `lv_arr[i]` is returning a Null Value which causes the runtime FATAL EXCEPTION with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

So When I review my code I found that there are some conflicts in the List Size which is in one place 44 and in another place it is 53 wherefore the when the value of i is 44 the list `lv_arr[i]=null` and comparison with null value gives rise to this Exception...

I successfully cleared it out in my code thanks to all of you..